# Cordova - how do I get icons to show against white status bar? (in iOS)

Tags: android, ios, cordova, statusbar

I want to change the status bar from black to white. The config.xml settings below achieved what I want on Android, but on iOS, the status bar is white and the icons are invisible. It seems the StatusBarStyle doesn't work on iOS.

```
  <preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#FFFFFF" />
  <preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="default" />
```

How do I get the icons to show up against a white status bar in iOS?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your `StatusBarStyle` to `blackopaque`

Comment: According to the documentation here, that's deprecated (https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/10.x/reference/cordova-plugin-statusbar/)

Comment: see https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/11.x/reference/cordova-plugin-statusbar/ this is the v11 doc